# Alchemy Websocket Server - How do I forcibly disconnect a client?

Tags: c#, websocket

I am trying out the Alchemy Websocket server and so far it is working however I can not figure out how to forcibly disconnect a client.

There is no Disconnect() method or anything similar on the WebSocketServer class.
There is also no Disconnect method or anything similar on the UserContext object which is returned as part of the server callbacks.

```
WebSocketServer _server;

public TestServer()
{
    _server = new WebSocketServer(90, IPAddress.Any);
    _server.OnConnect = OnConnect;

    _server.Start();
}

public void OnConnect(UserContext context)
{
    //no context.Disconnect() here
    //no _server.Disconnect(context) type method either  
}
```

Am I just missing something or is there no way to forcibly disconnect a client?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? If so, please post the answer yourself!

Comment: I never received an answer.  I am using the Fleck WebSocket server instead which has the option to disconnect an individual client.

Answer (score 0):

As per the client-server logic, a server cannot disconnect a client but can deny services to unauthenticated clients. Denying service to a client is almost the same as disconnecting the client.